# Build Palindrome from two strings

Tags: python, algorithm, palindrome

I want to write a python function that does this efficiently:

The function will take two strings, 'a' and 'b', and attempt to find the longest palindromic string
that can be formed such that it is a concatenation of a non-empty substring of 'a' and a non-empty
substring of 'b'. If there are multiple valid answers, it will return the lexicographically smallest one.
If no such string can be formed, it will return '-1'.

I have an inefficient solution that generates all the substrings of both strings, and then creates all possible concatenations whle tracking the longest which is a valid palindrome:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    """Check if a word is a palindrome."""
    reversed_word = word[::-1]
    return word == reversed_word


def all_substrings_of_word(word):
    """Generate all possible non-empty substrings of a given string."""
    substrings = []
    for sub_string_length in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        for i in range(len(word) - sub_string_length + 1):
            new_word = word[i:i + sub_string_length]
            substrings.append(new_word)
    return substrings


def buildPalindrome(a, b):
    """Attempt to find the longest palindromic string created by concatenating
    a substring of `a` with a substring of `b`."""
    sub_strings_a = all_substrings_of_word(a)
    sub_strings_b = all_substrings_of_word(b)

    # Generate all possible concatenations of substrings from `a` and `b`
    multiplexed_array = [
        word_a + word_b for word_a in sub_strings_a for word_b in sub_strings_b]

    # Find the best palindrome (longest, then lexicographically smallest)
    best_palindrome = ""
    for word in multiplexed_array:
        if is_palindrome(word):
            if len(word) > len(best_palindrome):
                best_palindrome = word
            elif len(word) == len(best_palindrome) and word < best_palindrome:
                best_palindrome = word

    return best_palindrome if best_palindrome else "-1"

print(buildPalindrome("bac", "bac"))   # EXPECTED OUTPUT -- aba
print(buildPalindrome("abc", "def"))   # EXPECTED OUTPUT -- -1
print(buildPalindrome("jdfh", "fds"))   # EXPECTED OUTPUT -- dfhfd
```

Can I please get an explanation on how this can be improved?

Comment: Example input with expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide an input for which your program is not fast enough (with time measurement), and what the desired running time is for that example (any limit?)

Comment: Added examples at the bottom of the code. I don't have concrete test cases on where the code wouldn't be fas enough. It's just my assumption through the time complexity analysis

Comment: So you are saying there is no efficiency problem? If you don't have concrete test cases that pose an efficiency problem, then what is the problem?

Comment: Given the above question and code, can you come up with an more efficient solution @trincot. The way @Scott Hunter suggested using a max heap for the `multiplexed_array`

Comment: I think you may be looking for the longest common substring between one string and the other reversed, but would need more examples to see if it fits.

Comment: @Nulo, no I don't think longest common substring covers it. The longest palindrome is not said to be evenly distributed over both input strings. For example, 75% of it might be in the first string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take this approach:

- Build a trie for all substrings in `b`. A suffix tree would be even better, as it is more efficient.
- Consider all possible "centers" for potential palindromes in the string `a`. So these can be *between* two consecutive characters (when palindrome has an even size) or *on* a character (when palindrome has an odd size). For each of these centers do:

  - Find the largest palindrome `p` at that center only considering string `a`
  - extend `p` to the left as long as the added characters (in the order of being added) are a word in the trie of `b`. This is a potential solution. Compare it with the longest palindrome so far to retain the longest.
  - If it is not possible to extend `p` in this way, then *shorten* `p` until a character is so removed that exists in `b`. In that case we have a potential solution.
  - If in the latter case there are no characters in `p` that occur in `b`, then we have no suitable palindrome at the chosen center.

Then turn the tables and apply the above procedure where `a` becomes the reversal of `b`, and `b` the reversal of `a`. This practically means we search for palindrome centers in the original `b`.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```
# Of the two given strings choose the one that is longest, or if equal, comes first in lexical order
def longest(x, y):
    return min((-len(x), x), (-len(y), y))[1]

def buildTrie(s):
    trie = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        node = trie
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            node = node.setdefault(s[j], {})
    return trie

def buildPalindromeTrincot(s1, s2):
    palin = ""
    # Two passes: one for where the center of a palindrome is in s1, one for the reverse case
    for a, b in ((s1, s2), (s2[::-1], s1[::-1])):
        # Build a trie for B substrings (could be suffixtree for better performance)
        trie = buildTrie(b)
        n = len(a)
        # Visit all possible centers in A for a potential solution of at least 2 characters 
        for center in range(2*n-1, 0, -1):
            # Get the offsets of the innermost characters that must be equal 
            #   for a palindrome of at least two characters
            mid1 = (center - 1)//2
            mid2 = (center + 2)//2
            # Get largest palindrome at this center in A alone: 
            #   `left` will point to the left-neighboring character to that palindrome
            left = next((left for left, right in zip(range(mid1, 0, -1), range(mid2, n)) 
                         if a[left] != a[right]), 
                        max(0, mid1 + mid2 - n))
            # Must extend the palindrome with a substring from B
            node = trie.get(a[left], None)
            if node is not None:  # We can extend the palindrome using B
                for left in range(left-1, -1, -1):
                    if a[left] not in node:
                        left += 1
                        break
                    node = node[a[left]]                    
            else: 
                # See if we can drop characters from the palindrome in A 
                #    until we can replace one with the same character from B
                left = next((left for left in range(left+1, mid1+1) if a[left] in trie), None)
                if left is None:
                    continue  # No solution found here
            palin = longest(a[left:mid2] + a[left:mid1+1][::-1], palin)
                
    return palin or "-1"
```

For input strings of around 40, this implementation runs 100 times faster than the original code you provided. For inputs of size 70, that becomes a factor of 1000 times. For inputs with strings of size 500, this implementation returns an answer in less than a second.

There is still room for improvement, like:

- Using a suffix tree instead of a trie
- Exiting early when the future palindromes can never be longer than the one already found
- Have the center move from the center of `a+b` and "fan" outward, so that a larger palindrome is found sooner. For this you'll need to have both tries built first as you'll toggle between one and the other.

But as the above code already brought a dramatic improvement, I didn't pursue any of these improvements.

Comment: Great stuff! will take some time to understand it before I ask more questions. I accepted it as the answer as it passes a lot more test cases than mine but it still times out for some. I can share some of the test cases with you if you're interested. Performance might indeed improve by replacing the trie with a suffix tree